# How to Auto Shut Down Azure Classic VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

We are using an Azure Classic Virtual Machine!! It does not show 'AutoShutDown' Blade. Is this feature not available for Classic VM? When I searched, there is also an option to use Runbook in Automation Account to do this. Is anyone used this with classic VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available with classic vms. its 2019, you should migrate to ARM anyway. but you could use custom powershell runbook to shutdown classic vms using a schedule.

you'd need to tag the resource groups (cant tag classic resources) and invoke the runbook hourly. [this](https://4c74356b41.com/post5781) would be a nice starting point. in fact it does what you ask for.